# do tanach teach original sin?

Tags: tanach

does that verses give a christian notion that man can not be righteous and have original sin?

isaiah 48:8

Neither did you hearken, neither did you know, nor was your ear opened from then, for I knew that you would deal treacherously, **and you were called transgressor from the womb.**

Job 9:2

"**Indeed, I know that it is so, but why should a man be righteous with God?**

Job 15:14

**What is man that he should be innocent, and that one born of woman should be just?**

Job 25:4

**How then can man be just with God, and how can one born of woman be clean?**

Psalm 14:3

**All have turned away; together they have spoiled; no one does good, not even one.**

Psalm 130:3

O God, if You keep [a record of] iniquities, **o Lord, who will stand?**

Psalm 143:2

And do not come to judgment with Your servant, **for no living being will be innocent before You.**

Psalm 51:7

**Behold, with iniquity I was formed, and with sin my mother conceived me.**

Genesis 8:21

And the Lord smelled the pleasant aroma, and the Lord said to Himself, "I will no longer curse the earth because of man, **for the imagination of man's heart is evil from his youth,** and I will no longer smite all living things as I have done.

Comment: No it is a Christian idea. Not Jewish.

Answer (score 1):

As you quote Psalms [51:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.51.7?lang=bi)

> הֵן־בְּעָו֥וֹן חוֹלָ֑לְתִּי וּ֝בְחֵ֗טְא יֶֽחֱמַ֥תְנִי אִמִּֽי׃
>
> Indeed I was born with iniquity; with sin my mother conceived me.

See Redak there (https://www.mgketer.org/tanach/27/51/7) who quotes

> תדע לך שהוא כן , שלאחר שעושין צרכיהם , זה הופך פניו לכאן וזה הופך פניו לכאן
>
> You should know that this is so, for after they have taken care of their needs (cohabitation), they turn away from each other.

This seems to mean as follows:

We have two types of sexual intercourse, intimate (as in a loving relationship) and non-intimate (e.g. as with regards to a prostitute).

The criticism is that, if the parent's intercourse was purely intimate, they would not turn away from each other after completion. The fact that they do indicates that there is a small element of non-intimacy present within their cohabitation.

So the notion of original sin here refers to the extent to which the intercourse is non-intimate.